# my search bar clashing with other inputs and list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a search bar that works perfectly on js fiddle, but upon implementation on a test website, it started clashing with some other input and un-ordered list elements, i believe the problem was from the JavaScript file. i tried to specify the ul and input it should target, but instead it broke and didn't work. please i need someone help to help me try it out. below is the html and js fie which works perfectly, but if one could give the JavaScript the input and ul class it should affect and hopefully it works, that would be very appreciated. please help me, i need this.

this is the html file

```
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

            <form class="">
                <div class="search form-group">
                  <input type="text" id="searchBox" class="search-field search__input" placeholder="Search" autoFocus autocomplete="off"/>
                  <button class="fa fa-search search__button"></button>
                    <ul id="searchResults" class="term-list hidden"></ul>
                </div>
            </form>
```

this is the javascript file

```
    var searchIndex = ["404 Error", "Address Bar", "Ajax", "Apache", "Autoresponder", "BitTorrent", "Blog", "Bookmark", "Bot", "Broadband", "Captcha", "Certificate", "Client", "Cloud", "Cloud Computing", "CMS", "Cookie", "CSS", "Cyberspace", "Denial of Service", "DHCP", "Dial-up", "DNS Record", "Domain Name", "Download", "E-mail", "Facebook", "FiOS", "Firewall", "FTP", "Gateway", "Google", "Google Drive", "Gopher", "Hashtag", "Hit", "Home Page", "HTML", "HTTP", "HTTPS", "Hyperlink", "Hypertext", "ICANN", "Inbox", "Internet", "InterNIC", "IP", "IP Address", "IPv4", "IPv6", "IRC", "iSCSI", "ISDN", "ISP", "JavaScript", "jQuery", "Meta Search Engine", "Meta Tag", "Minisite", "Mirror", "Name Server", "Packet", "Page View", "Payload", "Phishing", "POP3", "Protocol", "Scraping", "Search Engine", "Social Networking", "Socket", "Spam", "Spider", "Spoofing", "SSH", "SSL", "Static Website", "Twitter", "XHTML"];

    var input = document.getElementById("searchBox"),
      ul = document.getElementById("searchResults"),
      inputTerms, termsArray, prefix, terms, results, sortedResults;


    var search = function(e) {
      if (e.which == 40 || e.which == 38) return;
      inputTerms = input.value.toLowerCase();
      results = [];
      termsArray = inputTerms.split(' ');
      prefix = termsArray.length === 1 ? '' : termsArray.slice(0, -1).join(' ') + ' ';
      terms = termsArray[termsArray.length - 1].toLowerCase();

      for (var i = 0; i < searchIndex.length; i++) {
        var a = searchIndex[i].toLowerCase(),
          t = a.indexOf(terms);

        if (t > -1) {
          results.push(a);
        }
      }

      evaluateResults();
    };

    var evaluateResults = function() {
      if (results.length > 0 && inputTerms.length > 0 && terms.length !== 0) {
        sortedResults = results.sort(sortResults);
        appendResults();
      } else if (inputTerms.length > 0 && terms.length !== 0) {
        ul.innerHTML = '' + /* inside the colom is where the text for wrong searches */
          inputTerms +
          ''; /* inside the colom is where the text for wrong searches */

      } else if (inputTerms.length !== 0 && terms.length === 0) {
        return;
      } else {
        clearResults();
      }
    };

    var sortResults = function(a, b) {
      if (a.indexOf(terms) < b.indexOf(terms)) return -1;
      if (a.indexOf(terms) > b.indexOf(terms)) return 1;
      return 0;
    }

    var appendResults = function() {
      clearResults();
      for (var i = 0; i < sortedResults.length && i < 5; i++) {
        var _li = document.createElement("li"),
          result = prefix +
          sortedResults[i].toLowerCase().replace(terms, '<strong>' + terms + '</strong>');

        _li.innerHTML = result;

        ul.appendChild(_li);
      }

      li = $('li');
      liSelected = li.filter('.selected');
      $('li').click(function(e) {
        $('input').val($(this).text());
      });
      if (ul.className !== "term-list") {
        ul.className = "term-list";
      }
    };

    var clearResults = function() {
      ul.className = "term-list hidden";
      ul.innerHTML = '';
    };

    input.addEventListener("keyup", search, false);





    var li = $('li');
    var liSelected;
    $(window).keydown(function(e) {
      if (e.which === 40) {
        if (liSelected) {
          liSelected.removeClass('selected');
          next = liSelected.next();
          if (next.length > 0) {
            liSelected = next.addClass('selected');
          } else {
            liSelected = li.eq(0).addClass('selected');
          }
        } else {
          liSelected = li.eq(0).addClass('selected');
        }
        liSelected.trigger('click');
      } else if (e.which === 38) {
        if (liSelected) {
          liSelected.removeClass('selected');
          next = liSelected.prev();
          if (next.length > 0) {
            liSelected = next.addClass('selected');
          } else {
            liSelected = li.last().addClass('selected');
          }
        } else {
          liSelected = li.last().addClass('selected');
        }
        liSelected.trigger('click');
      }

    });
```

Comment: Define "It's clashing and it doesn't work". What's the current behaviour and what's the expected behaviour?

Comment: Please post a link to the jsfiddle url.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/opeodedeyi/zxnpoph7/

Comment: @jeremy it should work now, i forgot to add something to the html

Comment: @jeremy when i mean its clashing, i ean that i have another file input, and instead of the search result javascript to affect the search bars, it is affecting the file input one, i tried pointing it to the searchbars input but it doesnt work. i really need help with it. i also have the same problem with the list items. i have another ul in my navbar. but instead of being able to navigate through the search results li, it instead navigates through the navbars own and some how moves to the search's li. i also tried pointing the JavaScript to the searches li alone, but it also doesn't work.